# How can I reduce the complexity of this recursive function?

Tags: c#, recursion, time-complexity

It's basically to find the first key value in a nested json but I get a warning that is too complex just want to know if it's possible to make it more simple.

```
    private string FindBookName(string bookJsonString)
    {
        string bookName = "";
        if (bookJsonString.StartsWith("{") && bookJsonString.EndsWith("}")) {
            var bookDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(bookJsonString);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in bookDetails)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookName))
                {
                    var value = entry.Key.ToLower();
                    if (value == "bookname")
                    {
                        bookName = entry.Value.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (entry.Value is not string)
                    {
                        bookName = FindBookName(entry.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else if (bookJsonString.StartsWith("[") && bookJsonString.EndsWith("]"))
        {
            var arrayBookDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(bookJsonString);
            foreach (object value in arrayBookDetails)
            {
                if (value is not string && string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookName))
                {
                    bookName = FindBookName(value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return bookName;
    }
```

Comment: https://leonieponsioen.com/en/c-recursive-loop-through-json-files/

Comment: @Rafa, can you share the format/sample of JSON string that you are parsing in this method?

Comment: Ideally, the JSON string should deserialize to an object model that you declared. I.e. one or more classes that reflect the structure which could be recursive. Then you would recurse in your model instead of repeatedly deserializing JSON snippets.

Comment: Yes @KundanSinghChouhan "{\"movies\":{\"fiction\":\"893\",\"SciFi\":\"450\"},\"music\":[{\"pop\":{\"electroPop\":\"4\",\"hyperPop\":6}},{\"Rock\":\"empty\"},\"Reggeton\",\"House\"],\"Books\":{\"id\":\"5ed021980\",\"Authors\":\"Contemporary\",\"BookName\":\"AmericanPyscho\"}}"

Comment: @Rafa 1. Always post json as raw json and not as a c# or any other language escaped version 2. Add details to the question. The comment section is for asking to add more details but not for the details itself.